# LabVIEW - How to make the array search with multiple row and column?

Tags: labview

[block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQUEu.png)
[front panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc26p.png)

I've been working on this for 2-3 days and I can't seem to get it to work.

I need to be able to set the array "ingredients" to search on max 5 rows of the ingredients entered by the user referring to the array "All". then return the array row that contains at least 1 of the words in the array "Set using all specified ingredients" there must be no repetition of rows.

if you want the file, here is the link:
[File Labview](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1leiaoQkvr3OM1SdibzUdUBTiFvtoVZCl/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Could you leave some code snippets and give more context on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You actually got about 90% of the way there on your own.

That last 10% is down to not quite understanding the requirements that are set.
You are looking for an OR process during the selection, so that if any of the ingredients exist than that row will be selected. And by running this on the rows as a per-row process you are guaranteed not to have any duplicates.

> If ANY ingredient if found in ANY position on the row, pass-through that row.

[image: Front-panel of selection test]
[image: Back-panel of selection test]